# Batch conversion of .docx and .doc files to .rtf

Tags: windows, cmd, ms-word

I've tons of files in a folder with extension .docx and .doc which I need to convert to rtf because the software I'll use afterwards can better  handle rtf files.
In a Mac OS terminal, I would do this:

textutil -convert rtf ~/Desktop/Files2Convert/*.docx

Is there any similar approach under Windows OS?

Comment: Windows don't have a pre installed converter to handle the job for you. But I found this helpful [http://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-files-docx-format-rtf-format-docx2rtf]. It also support windows command line.

Comment: Office usually provides a batch file converter, although I've never used it. You might try asking in the IT Pro forum on TechNet where you'll find people who use that kind of thing. This isn't really a programming question...

Comment: This might be of interest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511559/converting-rtf-files-to-doc-and-then-doc-back-to-rtf-in-powershell-wmf-regi

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr - [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/) is free and phenomenal.

I haven't tried in Cygwin or command prompt for file conversion on Windows yet but I've been using Advanced Renamer for many years now and have been very happy. In fact, next paycheck I think I'll buy a personal license because it's been so great and I'm happy to support it since it's saved me tons of time and effort. It does have a file limit cap (I think 10,000, but I'd have to double check) for each operation, but that's pretty high and I rarely need that many. Also, you could just run it several times on larger groups broken into subsets.

It has a pretty straightforward interface and is a very very powerful tool.

Comment: `doc`, `docx` and `rtf` have very different encodings, so just renaming the files wouldn't do anything good.